# Adding target prerequisites via a pattern

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a project I'm working on, I have a directory full of source files which require a special executable to compile. My initial reaction is to do:

```
SomeDirectory/%.o: my-special-compiler
```

...to add the dependency for all `%.o` files.

Except of course this doesn't work, because pattern rules are special and while the above index will add a prerequisite for a *non* pattern rule, for pattern rules it seems to do nothing.

I don't have a list of all .o files in SomeDirectory at this point in the build system. Is there a way I can achieve the same effect without having to refactor my build system?

This is GNU Make, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not simply by adding a new rule.  You must list each of the object files and add that prerequisite specifically to them.  A pattern rule with no recipe [cancels the pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

Probably your best option is to follow the model created for [auto-dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) and automatically generate a file that contains that extra prerequisite, as a side-effect of creating the object file... then include it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a list of object files --- they're added piecemeal to a target as individual prerequisites in lines scattered throughout the build system. I know the target that they're being added to, but of course, adding dependencies there doesn't help.

Comment: Well, then the auto-dependency model will work, but requires a bit of effort.